# Definição de classe dentro de uma função ou de outra classe

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, classes, python-2.7

Já vi em alguns *scripts* definições de classes dentro de outras classes ou de funções tipo isso:

```
class Grok(object):

    class Foo(object):
        ...

    ...
```

Qual o motivo de realizar essa prática? É somente para não permitir a instanciação direta da classe definida internamente, e isso é realmente uma boa prática ou devo evitar seu uso a qualquer custo?

```
class Circle:
        class DrawingAPIOne:
                '''Implementation-specific abstraction'''
                def drawCircle(self, x, y, radius):
                        print("API 1 is drawing a circle at ({}, {}) with radius {}".format(x, y, radius))
        class DrawingAPITwo:
                '''Implementation-specific abstraction'''
                def drawCircle(self, x, y, radius):
                        print("API 2 is drawing a circle at ({}, {}) with radius {}".format(x, y, radius))
                         
        def __init__(self, x, y, radius):
                '''Implementation-independent abstraction; Initialize the necessary attributes'''
                self._x = x
                self._y = y
                self._radius = radius
        def drawWithAPIOne(self):
                '''Implementation-specific abstraction'''
                objectOfAPIone = self.DrawingAPIOne()
                objectOfAPIone.drawCircle(self._x, self._y, self._radius)
        def drawWithAPITwo(self):
                '''Implementation-specific abstraction'''
                objectOfAPItwo = self.DrawingAPITwo()
                objectOfAPItwo.drawCircle(self._x, self._y, self._radius)
        def scale(self, percent):
                '''Implementation-independent abstraction'''
                self._radius *= percent
```

Vi esse código no site: https://www.djangospin.com/design-patterns-python/bridge/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geralmente quanto menor o escopo de algo, menos polui o código, mais fica encapsulado e protegido de uso indevido e gera menos preocupações externas. Tudo que é público tem que tomar mais cuidado, não só com ele em si, mas qualquer coisa que criar precisa ser feito de forma a não conflitar com o que existe. Em escopo geral isso vai se tornando muito complicado.

Porém Python não trabalha com escopo de classe na forma como outras linguagens. Pelo que entendi tem até PEP conflitante sobre o assunto. Então a proteção acaba não ocorrendo. O que faz algum (pouco) sentido, afinal Python sempre foi uma linguagem de *script*, mais recentemente tem tentado deixar de ser e aí o escopo melhor definido e protegido passar ser mais importante.

Por isso mesmo a maior parte das vezes que criar uma classe dentro de um escopo tão pequena em uma linguagem sem cerimônia como Python, provavelmente está seguindo boa prática da forma como é pior, sem saber por quê, sem ter um motivo real para usar assim, só faz porque viu alguém fazendo. E adivinhe? Muitos códigos que você vê assim é porque a pessoa apenas "seguiu boa prática" sem saber por quê, sem identificar se o contexto exigia assim. Geralmente não é bom usar.

E cuidado com exemplos abstratos, eles costumam mostrar um mecanismo, e não como fazer em produção.

Este é um exemplo que tem como resolver de outra forma, usando *lambda*, por exemplo. Na verdade na forma escrita sequer precisa desta abstração.

Comment: "Essencialmente é isto mesmo, você limita o uso da classe aquele escopo e ela só pode ser instanciada ali dentro." por que começar uma resposta com algo essesncialmente, 100% errado? É Python - você não "limita o escopo"  - a classe nested fica num namespace da classe de fora, mas qualquer código tem acesso.

Comment: @jsbueno Ok, pra classes dentro de classe, e classe dentro de função?